# What to do with a WCF service client in faulted state?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I consume a WCF service **asynchronously**. If I can't connect to the service or an exception occurs it went to faulted state and it writes the error to the `Error` property of the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`.

What do I have to do with the service client? I cannot close it because it would throw a `CommunicationObjectFaultedException`. What else do I have to do after logging the error?

Here's my code:

```
MyServiceClient serviceClient = new MyServiceClient();

//Close the connection with the Service or log an error
serviceClient.JustAMethod += (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args) =>
{
    if (args.Error != null)
    {
        //Log error
        ErrorHandler.Log(args.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        serviceClient.Close();
    }
};

//Call the service
serviceClient.JustAMethodAsync();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can abort it, and create a new one. Here's a fragment from a class I wrote that deals with that issue. Everything that it touches here is legal to touch when the client is in the faulted state.

```
if (_client.InnerChannel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
{
    _client.Abort();
    _client = new TServiceClient();
}
```

`TServiceClient` is any subclass of `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TIClientInterface>`.

I wrote that because I've had constant access issues calling webservices from the server end of an MVC4 web app, with the browser client accessing the page via RDS.

**However, as of now, the above code isn't in use.** For reasons I don't understand, it had a lot more access-denied exceptions than the simplest approach of invariably creating a new client for every call, and disposing it after. I never bother checking faulted state because I never use them for more than one call anyway.

```
using (var cli = new Blah.Blah.FooWCFClient())
{
    _stuff = cli.GetStuff();
}
```

...in a try/catch, of course. If you see any issues with the client-caching/Abort approach, I'd suggest you try creating a new client for every call. Maybe it costs a few cycles, but it's silly to call a web service and *then* start worrying about runtime efficiency. That horse has left the barn.

I don't know how this would interact with the asynchronous business, other than a vague intuition about keeping things simple and not sharing anything across threads.

Welcome to my nightmare. I haven't yet identified the cause of our access issues, but I doubt things can possibly be that bad for you. So I hope at least one of those two options will work out.

UPDATE

Here's some .tt-generated service wrapper code from our XAML application. Every web service call method gets wrapped like this, and it's been bulletproof for years. I would recommend doing essentially this:

```
public static POCO.Thing GetThing(int thingID)
{
    var proxy = ServiceFactory.CreateNewFooWCFClientInstance();
    try
    {
        var returnValue = proxy.GetThing(thingID);
        proxy.Close();
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //  ***********************************
        //  Error logging boilerplate redacted
        //  ***********************************
        proxy.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that it's just as well if you don't reuse WCF client objects at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do with it. Create a new one and let the garbage collector collect the other one.